# custom scroll able multi color seek bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I want seek-bar which selector stay sticky and it's bottom scale scrolls horizontally and it's also shows diff time slots.

[image]

I already tried https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/
but it's not as i want

Anyone have any idea how to create this control

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to create custom using collectionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ruler-picker library for the ruller view

Then modify some existing method to show text for diff time slots

And also used canvas to draw above green line and some mathematical calculation to get value of selected time slot

After so many changes i get control like below

[image]